# Verificar Radio input - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, enums

Preciso verificar qual entre 3 Radios diferentes esta selecionado para uma verificação.

```
<input type="radio" name="frame" id="framework" value="react"> React
<input type="radio" name="frame" id="framework" value="angular"> Angular
<input type="radio" name="frame" id="framework" value="vue"> Vue
```

Queria usar o Switch há apenas 2 resultados - Angular e React retornam o mesmo - então seria preciso uma verificação de dado enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Preciso verificar qual entre 3 Radios diferentes esta selecionado para uma verificação.

Para verificar se uns dos `input type=radio` foi selecionado faça o seguinte código:

```js
function escolhido() {
  var res = '';
  const items = document.getElementsByName('frame');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].checked) {
      res = items[i].value
      break;
    }
  }  
  return res;
}

function verificar() {
  const res = escolhido();
  if (res === '') {
    alert('nenhum item foi selecionado');
    return false;
  }
  alert('O item selecionado foi ' + res);
  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="frame" id="framework" value="react"> React
<input type="radio" name="frame" id="framework" value="angular"> Angular
<input type="radio" name="frame" id="framework" value="vue"> Vue

<button type="button" onclick="verificar()">Verificar</button>
```

ou um código resumido:

```js
function verificar()
{
  const item = document
       .querySelectorAll("input[name^='frame']:checked");       
  if (item.length === 1) {
    console.log(item[0].value);
    return item[0].value;      
  }
  console.log('Não selecionado');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="frame" id="framework" value="react"> React
<input type="radio" name="frame" id="framework" value="angular"> Angular
<input type="radio" name="frame" id="framework" value="vue"> Vue

<button type="button" onclick="verificar()">Verificar</button>
```

onde a busca seria pelo nome do `radio` e se o mesmo está selecionado.

---

Você disse:

> Queria usar o Switch há apenas 2 resultados - Angular e React retornam o mesmo - então seria preciso uma verificação de dado enum

eu fiquei mesmo sem entender o proposito da utilização do `switch`, acredito que a solução é somente a busca do selecionado e o `switch` talvez não traria um resultado dinâmico.